# CURL and dropdown array

Tags: php, html, curl

I'm trying to submit a form via POST, however the website has regionand city dropdown, the dropdown is constructed like this

There ar dropdowns for each region, but their hidden so most of them are region_id => '', however my post and their post are identical, yet it still says please select a city,

Their POST

```
Array
(
    [region] => MY04
    [district] => Array
        (
            [MY14] => 
            [MY10] => 
            [MY07] => 
            [MY01] => 
            [MY02] => 
            [MY03] => 
            [MY04] => ML001
            [MY05] => 
            [MY06] => 
            [MY08] => 
            [MY09] => 
            [MY11] => 
            [MY12] => 
            [MY13] => 
            [MY15] => 
            [MY16] => 
            [MY99] => 
        )

    [streetnumber] => 
    [streetname] => 
    [streetname2] => 
    [postcode] => 
    [longitude] => 
    [latitude] => 
    [submit] => Next >
    [hidden_listing_id] => 
    [process] => 4e870291af244
)
```

My array

```
    Array
(
    [region] => MY04
    [district] => Array
        (
            [MY14] => 
            [MY01] => 
            [MY02] => 
            [MY03] => 
            [MY04] => ML001
            [MY05] => 
            [MY06] => 
            [MY07] => 
            [MY08] => 
            [MY09] => 
            [MY16] => 
            [MY12] => 
            [MY13] => 
            [MY10] => 
            [MY11] => 
        )

    [streetnumber] => 
    [streetname] => 
    [streetname2] => 
    [postcode] => 
    [longitude] => 
    [latitude] => 
    [submit] => Next >
    [hidden_listing_id] => 
    [process] => 4e87114ddef0e
)
```

Been stuck on this for a while, anyone have any ideas why this is happening? Thank you!

Comment: Solved by doing [district][state] = value, for each one 
$post["district[".$st."]"] = $city;

Comment: Write yourself an answer so this question gets flagged as answered, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by doing [district][state] = value, for each one $post["district[".$st."]"] = $city;